# Can't restore Bower packages in ASP.NET core application?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, bower, asp.net-core-2.1

I downloaded [this sample app](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/security/authentication/identity/sample/src/ASPNETCore-IdentityDemoComplete/IdentityDemo), there are missing bower packages:

[image]

When I restore them, this shows up in the output window:

> PATH=.\node_modules.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team
>   Explorer\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team
>   Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Web\External\Bower.cmd" install bootstrap#3.3.7
>   --force-latest bower bootstrap#3.3.7          EINVRES Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/bootstrap failed with 502

.NET core version on my machine: `2.1.302`

Visual Studio version : 15.7.4

bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "jquery": "2.2.0",
    "jquery-validation": "1.14.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.6"
  }
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: If you open the link from the message (i.e. https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/bootstrap) you will see: `This Bower version is deprecated. Please update it: npm install -g bower. The new registry address is https://registry.bower.io` and chrome tools will show that the status code os 502 (Bad gateway). I guess update bower and try again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open .bowerrc file located in the root folder of the project.
2. Add `registry` property to the file's content, pointing to the new bower registry. It should look like this:

   ```
   {
     "registry": "https://registry.bower.io",
     "directory": "wwwroot/lib"
   }
   ```

Read this: [Workaround for Bower Version Deprecation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/07/05/workaround-for-bower-version-deprecation/)